# SQL: Check for URL

Tags: mysql, sql, url, select

I have multiple products from differente stores in my shop and want to get one specified product. This is possible with the url because every url is unique!

But if I want to get values by the url I get a error and 0 products are displayed although there is exactly one row matching my query...

How can I fix that and do queries with the url?
[image]

My query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_all_import_xml`
WHERE name = 'Battlefield 4' AND
      price = 7.85 AND
      shop = 7941 AND
      url = "https://www.kinguin.net/category/4498/battlefield-4-eu-origin-cd-key/?nosalesbooster=1&country_store=1&currency=EUR"
```

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Updated .......

Comment: Without seeing the actual data in the `Battlefield 4` table, I can't say whether or not the results are unexpected.

Comment: You can see the data in the picture at the bottom?

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it involves a simple typographical error.  The URLs in the table do not match to the one against which you are comparing.  All your data URLs have query strings, which you ignore, and all are `http`, _not_ `https`.

Comment: Yeah I see. The one is `http` and the other is `https`. But why I still get this big amount of errors in the upper left corner of the picture?

Comment: It also appears that you did not close the quote around the URL.  _All_ these errors are just simple typos.

Comment: I close the quote, see: `SELECT *
FROM wp_all_import_xml
WHERE url = "http://www.kinguin.net/category/4498/battlefield-4-eu-origin-cd-key/?nosalesbooster=1&country_store=1&currency=EUR"`

Comment: Not a MySQL guy, but maybe you need to escape the question mark: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,206017,206031#msg-206031

Comment: But if I replace the `https` with `http`it is working without escaping. But do I have to worry about the yellow box? - Because it is not edging the url but rather the category... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLxINxZFzovYVcyUER2RE1SMVU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try running this version without the price comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_all_import_xml`
WHERE name = 'Battlefield 4' AND
      -- price = 7.85 AND
      shop = 7941 AND
      url = 'https://www.kinguin.net/category/4498/battlefield-4-eu-origin-cd-key/?nosalesbooster=1&country_store=1&currency=EUR';
```

Does it return anything?  If so, your problem is probably a floating point comparison on price.  The correct fix is to change the data type of `price` to be a `decimal`/`numeric`.  You can put in a hack like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_all_import_xml`
WHERE name = 'Battlefield 4' AND
      price >= 7.85 - 0.001 AND price <= 7.85 + 0.001 AND
      shop = 7941 AND
      url = 'https://www.kinguin.net/category/4498/battlefield-4-eu-origin-cd-key/?nosalesbooster=1&country_store=1&currency=EUR';
```

If that doesn't work, then try using `LIKE` on the URL:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_all_import_xml`
WHERE name = 'Battlefield 4' AND
      -- price = 7.85 AND
      shop = 7941 AND
      url like 'https://www.kinguin.net/category/4498/battlefield-4-eu-origin-cd-key/%;
```

To see if this returns anything.

Comment: If I use `http` instand of `https` it is working. But I am a little bit confused. Do I have to worry about the yellow box? - Because it is not edging the url but rather the category and I selected the URL...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLxINxZFzovYVcyUER2RE1SMVU/view